# How to find the types of elements in a list in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-re

I want to find out the correct types of elements in a list in python. For example,

I am trying the previous code for now and I am unable to get the correct output.

```
list_of_elements = ['string', '23', '11.04', 'True']

types_list = {}

for x, i in enumerate(list_of_elements, 1):
    if str(x):
        types_list['id'] = i
        types_list['type'] = 'String'
    elif int(x):
        types_list['id'] = i
        types_list['type'] = 'Integer'
    elif bool(x):
        types_list['id'] = i
        types_list['type'] = 'Boolean'
    elif float(x):
        types_list['id'] = i
        types_list['type'] = 'Float'

print(types_list)
```

I want to get the result below:

output:

```
{
{id:1, type:'String'},
{id:2, type:'Integer'},
{id:3, type:'Float'},
{id:4, type:'Boolean'}
}
```

Comment: ALL of those things are strings.  There are no integers and no booleans.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: And, as a side note, your `for x,i` is backwards.  The index comes first.

Comment: What type should the strings `'inf'` and `'nan'` have?

Comment: That is also a doubt for me. Thanks for asking. I think it will be treated as a string as it consists of all letters.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you reasonably trust<sup>1</sup> the source of the strings in `list_of_elements`, you can attempt to interpret the entries as Python literals using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

list_of_elements = ['string', '23', '11.04', 'True']

types_list = []

for i, x in enumerate(list_of_elements, 1):
    try:
        parsed_x = ast.literal_eval(x)
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        # Keep as str
        parsed_x = x
    
    types_list.append(
        {
            "id": i,
            "type": type(parsed_x).__name__
        }
    )
print(types_list)
```

outputs

```
[{'id': 1, 'type': 'str'}, {'id': 2, 'type': 'int'}, {'id': 3, 'type': 'float'}, {'id': 4, 'type': 'bool'}]
```

Do note that this also opens the door to resolving strings to *any* Python literal type, not just `str`s, `float`s, `int`s, and `bool`s as requested. So, for example, the string `'{1, 2, 3}'` will be reported as having the type `set`, not `str`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that it is possible to crash the Python interpreter using maliciously crafted input to `ast.literal_eval`. Do not pass it strings that you do not trust.

Comment: Excellent answer! Perhaps you must catch TypeError and other errors also

Comment: @RicVillalba Interesting point. I am unsure. I think the other possible errors would be indicative of a problem, and are probably better propagated than caught. E.g., a `TypeError` would mean that the input wasn't a string (unexpected), and a `MemoryError` would indicate an very extreme input value (also unexpected)

Comment: One edge case to consider: this approach reports `str` for the string `'nan'`, while some of the other approaches will report `float`.

Comment: This gives me the exact result but sometimes I need to use some values like 'NA'. This should not be given as a string. These are some special values that are to be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

The most robust way I know to interpret strings into types is to try each one and catch resulting `ValueError` as they occur.

```py
def text_to_value(text):
    '''convert str to a float, int,  bool or str'''
    try:
        # try to return an integer
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # try to return a float instead
            return float(text)
        except ValueError:
            # now try for a bool or plain text
            return {'True': True, 'False': False}.get(text, text)

elements = ['string', '23', '11.04', 'True']
values = [text_to_value(text) for text in elements]
types = [type(value) for value in values]
```

Results:

```py
types == [str, int, float, bool]
values == ['string', 23, 11.04, True]
```

Note: It's important to try `int` before `float`, since most valid `int` literals will also validly parse to `float`.

Comment: @S3DEV Clarified to say "most robust" rather than best. Other approaches can be faster, and there are also approaches which allow more flexibility.

Comment: I wonder if it's _most_ or _all_ valid `int` literals that will also parse as `float`s. Even ints that exceed the range of a float will still parse as +/-`inf`

Comment: @Brian That's true, though I might not consider converting a potentially precise and finite `int` as `inf` to be *as* valid... It is IEEE compliant, so I suppose I must hold my nose and declare it "valid". XD

Answer (score 0):

try convert every string to a type, for example

```
for x in list_element:
   try:
      element = int(x)
   except:
      element = None # Cannot convert data to int, because is not a int
```

Use something like that for every type (int, float, bool) and the last type you should test have to be str, because all the data is string, so the element should be a string if not is int,float,bool.

Comment: This approach does have some subtitles that would be worth addressing in a complete answer. E.g. evaluating `bool(x)` doesn't provide the information that this answer suggests it would

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one and got nearly my desired output but the answer 1 and answer 2 almost give my desired result. Some elements like 'NA', 'nan', and 'inf can cause some problems. These values should go to the other types except the 'String' data type. I think this could be optimized for my desired result

```
first_row_elements_in_csv_2 = ['drtger', '23', '55678', 'edrzt', 'True', 'False',
 '234.67', '658969.89', '0', '1', 'NA']
first_row_elements_in_csv = ['Storm', 'folium', '29', '23020', '790', 'True']
def types_in_order(first_row_elements_in_csv_2):
    types_promise = {}
    types_id = {}
    types = []
    for i, x in enumerate(first_row_elements_in_csv_2,1):
        if x == 'True' or x == 'False' or x == '0' or x == '1':
            types_id = {}
            types_id['id'] = i
            types_id['type'] = 'Boolean'
            types.append(types_id)
        elif bool(re.match("^[0-9]", x)):
            types_id = {}
            types_id['id'] = i
            types_id['type'] = 'Integer'
            types.append(types_id)
        elif str(x) and x != 'NA':
            types_id = {}
            types_id['id'] = i
            types_id['type'] = 'String'
            types.append(types_id)
        else:
            types_id = {}
            types_id['id'] = i
            types_id['type'] = 'Float'
            types.append(types_id)
    types_promise['data'] = types
    return types_promise
        
print(types_in_order(first_row_elements_in_csv_2))

output:

{'data': [{'id': 1, 'type': 'String'}, 
{'id': 2, 'type': 'Integer'}, 
{'id': 3, 'type': 'Integer'}, 
{'id': 4, 'type': 'String'}, 
{'id': 5, 'type': 'Boolean'}, 
{'id': 6, 'type': 'Boolean'}, 
{'id': 7, 'type': 'Integer'}, 
{'id': 8, 'type': 'Integer'}, 
{'id': 9, 'type': 'Boolean'}, 
{'id': 10, 'type': 'Boolean'}, 
{'id': 11, 'type': 'Float'}]}
```